# Unable to use 'await' in a non-'async' method

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, asynchronous, async-await

I'm developing for Windows phone 8, and am trying to connect to a server using the Windows.Networking namespace. (System.Net sockets aren't really supported in wp8) So I call to make the connection:

```
socket.ConnectAsync(e);
```

And I get the error "Because this call is not awaited, execution of the..." which is fair enough, given that the await keyword should be used here. However, when I add this in:

```
await socket.ConnectAsync(e);
```

I get the error: "the 'await' operator can only be used within an async method."

This has been more than somewhat frustrating. I can't really fiddle around with how this works on the method that I'm calling, as this is a precompiled function, with the signature:

```
public IAsyncAction ConnectAsync(EndpointPair endpointPair);
```

What should I do here? In my limited understanding this seems to be a problem with .net, and is driving me mad! Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Problem is solved now jlahd, I was trying to open a socket using the await keyword, in a method which wasn't using the async keyword.

Comment: You should never ignore compiler warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have *your* function, the one calling `socket.ConnectAsync(e)`, asynchronous as well.

```
void MyFunction()
{
    await socket.ConnectAsync(e);
}
```

gets you the error you are seeing. Change it to

```
async Task MyFunction()
{
    await socket.ConnectAsync(e);
}
```